# Variable Reassignment - C

Tags: c, variables

With the input:

```
5, 08:00:00, 2, 30
5, 08:00:10, 6, 0
```

The program should output:

```
Heart Rate:
08:00:00: 30
```

But instead it outputs:

```
Heart Rate:
08:00:10: 30
```

Basically, the problem i'm encountering is that for each Element struct, it prints the same timestamp, being the timestamp last entered.

Can someone help? I'm sorry if i'm being too brief, I didn't want to overload this post. If you need more clarification please let me know.

```
typedef struct{
    char *timestamp;
    int value;
}Element;

typedef char f_string[MAXCHARS + 1];

typedef struct {
    int nfields;
    f_string field[MAXFIELDS];
} csv_line;

void main(){
    int i, j;
    csv_line data;
    int run = 1;
    Element temperature;
    temperature.timestamp = "\0";
    temperature.value = -1;
    Element heart_rate;
    heart_rate.timestamp = "\0";
    heart_rate.value = -1;
    Element systolic_pressure;
    systolic_pressure.timestamp = "\0";
    systolic_pressure.value = -1;
    Element diastolic_pressure;
    diastolic_pressure.timestamp = "\0";
    diastolic_pressure.value = -1;
    Element respiration_rate;
    respiration_rate.timestamp = "\0";
    respiration_rate.value = -1;

    /* initialize health data records for each patient */

    for( i=0; i < MAXPATIENTS; i++ ){
            record[i].id = i + 1;
            for( j=0; j < MAXTYPES; j++ ){
                record[i].buffer[j].start = 0;
            record[i].buffer[j].end = 0;
            }
        }   
    printf("Welcome to the Health Monitoring System\n\n");

    while (run == 1) {  

        data = get_line();

        char *timestamp = data.field[1];
        int value = atoi(data.field[3]);
        int type = atoi(data.field[2]);

        switch(type) {
            case 1:
                temperature.timestamp = timestamp;
                temperature.value = value;
                break;
            case 2:
                heart_rate.timestamp = timestamp;
                heart_rate.value = value;
                break;
            case 3:
                systolic_pressure.timestamp = timestamp;
                systolic_pressure.value = value;
                break;
            case 4:
                diastolic_pressure.timestamp = timestamp;
                diastolic_pressure.value = value;
                break;
            case 5:
                respiration_rate.timestamp = timestamp;
                respiration_rate.value = value;
                break;
            case 6:
                run = 0;
                break;
        }   
    }
    print_data(atoi(data.field[0]), temperature, heart_rate, systolic_pressure, diastolic_pressure,
        respiration_rate);

    printf("\nEnd of input\n");
}
void print_data(int id, Element temperature, Element heart_rate, Element systolic_pressure,
            Element diastolic_pressure, Element respiration_rate) {
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Readings for Patient ID = %d are:\n", id);
    printf("Temperature:\n");
    printf("%s: %.1f\n", temperature.timestamp, (float)temperature.value / 10);
    printf("Heart Rate:\n");
    printf("%s: %d\n", heart_rate.timestamp, heart_rate.value);
    printf("Systolic Pressure\n");
    printf("%s: %d\n", systolic_pressure.timestamp, systolic_pressure.value);
    printf("Diastolic Pressure\n");
    printf("%s: %d\n", diastolic_pressure.timestamp, diastolic_pressure.value);
    printf("Respiration Rate\n");
    printf("%s: %d\n", respiration_rate.timestamp, respiration_rate.value);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: Copying a pointer does not copy the memory it points to.

Comment: Then how should I go about this?

Comment: Hard to advise without seeing how your defined your data structures.  But it's a bigger topic.  Basic understanding of pointers and memory is something you need to learn almost immediately after your first "hello world" program.  And this question becomes more about "how do I program in C" instead of "how do I fix my problem".

Comment: I've worked with pointers very minimally; I'm still learning and experimenting with them. I've added the structs that are being used.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) indent consistently, indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  Never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is visible even with variable width font.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  3) include the `#include` statements so we do not have to guess.

Comment: when any sub function body is after the place in the code where it is called, then there must be a `prototype` for that function before where it is first called. (in most cases right before `main()` )

Comment: the function: `get_line()` does not exist,  Perhaps you meant: `getline()`

Comment: when posting a question, always include the `#defined` statements.  in this case for `MAXTYPES`  (note: expected practice when #define'ing names is for the names to be all caps AND the root words separated by an underscore.  I.E. `MAX_TYPES`  Similar considerations for `MAXCHARS` and`MAXFIELDS`

Comment: following the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* makes the code much much easier to understand and to document with `doxygen` or `javadoc`

Comment: why do you use `"\0"` instead of `""`?

Comment: your question was about the timestamps, BUT the posted code does not include how the `data` was input nor how the `records[]` was set.  Please fix the compile problems, the style problems, and add the (many) missing parts and then we should be able to help you

Comment: record[] and the underlying struct is not defined.

Comment: this line: ` data = get_line();` is very unlikely to fill in the struct csv_line;   It might be better to place the `&data` as a parameter to get_line() so `get_line()` can fill in the fields.

Answer (score 0):

with this input:

```
5, 08:00:00, 2, 30
5, 08:00:10, 6, 0
```

and assuming (big assumption as the code for `get_line()` is not supplied)

that the first call to `get_line()` results in data containing:

```
4, { "5", "08:00:00", "2", "30" }


data.field[0][] = "5"
data.field[1][] = "08:00:00" 
data.field[2][] = "2"
data.field[3][] = "30"
```

then these three lines:

```
char *timestamp = data.field[1];
int value = atoi(data.field[3]);
int type = atoi(data.field[2]);
```

result in:

```
timestamp contains a pointer to data.field[1]
value     contains: 30
type      contains: 2
```

then `case 2:` results in:

```
 heart_rate.timestamp = timestamp; = pointer to data.field[1]
 heart_rate.value = value;         = 30
```

Then the next line is read, into the same memory as the first line

then ... the call to print_data():  which contains these two lines:

```
printf("Heart Rate:\n");
printf("%s: %d\n", heart_rate.timestamp, heart_rate.value);
```

Where 'heart_rate.timestamp' still points to the memory location in `data` which now contains the info from the second line.

Which is why the unexpected output.

to fix this problem:  this line:

```
char *timestamp = data.field[1];
```

needs to be changed to:

```
char *timestamp = strdup(data.field[1]);
```

Of course this adds some more code requirements:

```
1) check (!=NULL) the returned value from `strdup()` 
    to assure the operation was successful.
2) before exiting the program, need to pass each 'timestamp' to `free()`

free( heart_rate.timestamp );
```